# How do I bold a specific column and all column headers in xtable in knitr (print.xtable)

Tags: knitr, xtable

I am having difficulty understanding how to bold both a specific column and all the column headers using print.xtable

Answer (score 0):

If you may also consider a markdown-only solution:

```
> pander(head(mtcars), emphasize.strong.cols = 2:3, split.table = Inf)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        &nbsp;           mpg   cyl   disp    hp   drat   wt    qsec   vs   am   gear   carb 
----------------------- ----- ----- ------- ---- ------ ----- ------ ---- ---- ------ ------
     **Mazda RX4**       21   **6** **160** 110   3.9   2.62  16.46   0    1     4      4   

   **Mazda RX4 Wag**     21   **6** **160** 110   3.9   2.875 17.02   0    1     4      4   

    **Datsun 710**      22.8  **4** **108**  93   3.85  2.32  18.61   1    1     4      1   

  **Hornet 4 Drive**    21.4  **6** **258** 110   3.08  3.215 19.44   1    0     3      1   

 **Hornet Sportabout**  18.7  **8** **360** 175   3.15  3.44  17.02   0    0     3      2   

      **Valiant**       18.1  **6** **225** 105   2.76  3.46  20.22   1    0     3      1   
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The header will be automatically rendered with bold/emphasized font by `pandoc`  by default. And you can fine-tune that via CSS or the LaTeX template.